# Spinon is charge neutral or has a unit charge?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, gauge-theory

I have studied that spinons are charge neutral particles and have spin 1/2. But in XG Wen’s book (quantum field theory for many body system), it is mentioned that spinon coupled to gauge field carries a unit charge! I don’t understand this.